# Не запускается gdx-setup

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Не запускается jar файл gdx-setup. При нажатии ничего не происходит. Раньше у меня был 32х разрядный процессор. Все работало. Теперь 64. Windows 10 x64 java Version 8 Update 181.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуте в cmd пройти к директории gdx-setup, а затем введите `java -jar gdx-setup.jar`.

Либо можно зажать правой кнопкой на файл, затем нажать "Открыть с помощью" и там выбрать JRE.

Если напишет `"java" не является внутренней или внешней командой...`, тогда в поиске по программам введите "***Изменение системных переменных среды***", затем нажмите "***Переменные среды***". В поле "***Системные переменные***" найдите переменную `Path` и нажмите "***Изменить***". В появившемся окне нажмите "***Создать***" и введите путь к JDK bin.

Пример пути: `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin`.

Comment: К сожалению не работает

Comment: @ItsGonnaBeMe пишет какую-нибудь ошибку?